# Probability of coin being double red

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

There is a bag containing four coins, the first coin is red on both sides, the second is blue on both sides, the third coin has a red side and a green side, and the fourth coin has a red side and blue side. A randomly drawn coin from the bag and is placed on a table in front of you, You see a red side of the coin. What are the odds the other side of the coin is red?

> My intuition is that this is a conditional probability. We are looking
> for the probability of a double red given that we see a red. The
> probability of seeing a red face is $\frac12$ and the probability of
> picking a double red is $\frac14$.
>
> $\frac{\frac14}{\frac12} = \frac12$
>
> Is this correct? If so, what is the intuition as to why the answer
> would not be $\frac13$, as there are $3$ coins with a red face where
> $1$ is double sided.

Comment: The intuition is that each face is equally likely to be seen, and the opposite face likely equally to be the face down side.  If there are four red faces of which two have red as their opposite face, then then the conditional probability is $\frac24=\frac12$

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative intuition:

You conduct an experiment $8$ times, so that each of the two sides of each of the $4$ coins is face-up one of the $8$ times.

Then, because the face-up side is red, you can presume that of the $8$ equally likely faces that might have appeared, the $4$ faces that are not red, did not appear.

So, you have $4$ equally likely faces, each of which is red, that represent that the face that you see is red.  Of these $4$ faces, exactly $2$ of the $4$ faces have the color red on the opposite face.